# Foundation Slider fails after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, zurb-foundation

I have a couple of sliders on a form that submits to an ajax request. The form updates the contents fine but the sliders fail to work after the initial ajax call. I have an onchange event that works fine before I submit the form:

```
$('#capacity-slider').on('change', function(){
    var v = $('#capacity-slider').attr('data-slider');
    $('#capacity-input').val(v);
});
```

But this event fails to even register after the form is submitted via ajax. If I was to post a standard http request multiple times it works fine. Via ajax I can continue to submit the form multiple times but the slider fails after the first go.

If I include the line below after the ajax call:

```
$(document).foundation('reflow');
```

Then the slider itself works, but I can't get it to register any events, so it's rendered useless.

Has anyone had any experience with this that they can share?

Thanks so much,
Steve

Comment: Can you provide your ajax submit code? I don't think the slider is failing, it needs to be refreshed so that the DOM can add another 'change' listener to it.

Comment: Yep, thanks - I think you're right. I'll have another play around and update the post accordingly.

Comment: I"m having the same problem - I'm trying to listen for a change event on a slider that gets loaded via ajax.  Do you remember what you did?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the change listener to the new slider and the foundation('reflow')